# Javascript regex for words between characters

Tags: javascript, regex

As the title states, I tried making regex for `%George%<Croissant>|2|10.3$`

The point is it has to match only the name between the both `%` and the product between both `<>` and then the numbers between `|`

However, if the name doesn't start with capital letters followed by only lowercase letters, it is invalid hence not matched. The regex I made is:

`/%(?<name>[A-Z][a-z]*)%<(?<product>[A-Za-z]*)>\|(?<quantity>(\d+))\|(?<price>(\d+\.\d*\$))/g`

- This is a match `%George%<Croissant>|2|10.3$` (has proper name between the % which has a capital letter start start and followed to the end by lowercase letters), product (the product is between the < and >), a number between both | and final number (which is the final number and has to have $ in order to be valid)
- This does NOT match `%InvalidName%<Croissant>|2|10.3$` (because the name is invalid)
- This does NOT match `%Peter%<Gum>1.3$` (missing number from both |, it has to have 2 numbers.

Tested at regex101 and it matches only `%George%<Croissant>|2|10.3$` .

`%Valid%<Valid>valid|10|valid20$` is valid too because it has a Proper name (1 capital letter followed by only lowercase letters, has product which is <`Valid`>, has number between |`10`| and has a number at the end |valid`20$`

Comment: If `%Valid%<Valid>valid|10|valid20$` should be valid, you can make the decimal part optional, and match optional word characters before and after the pipe `%(?<name>[A-Z][a-z]*)%<(?<product>[A-Za-z]*)>\w*\|(?<quantity>(\d+))\|[^\W\d]*(?<price>(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\$))` see https://regex101.com/r/mKrSdI/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird this is what i was looking for! You have non-matching group which i tried to make but didn't succeed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match both patterns, you can match optional word characters `\w*\|` before the pipe at group *quantity*, and match optional word chars without digits `y>(\d+))`  before group *price*.

To match both prices, you have to make the decimal part optional, because the pattern that you tried expects at least 1 or more digits and a dot using `\d+\.\d*`

You can also omit the extra capture group in quantity as the digits are already in a named capture group.

```
%(?<name>[A-Z][a-z]*)%<(?<product>[A-Za-z]*)>\w*\|(?<quantity>\d+)\|[^\W\d]*(?<price>(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\$))
```

**Explanation**

- `%(?<name>[A-Z][a-z]*)%` Group `name` between `%`, match at least an uppercase char A-Z and optional lowercase chars a-z
- `<(?<product>[A-Za-z]*)>` Group `product` Match optional chars A-Za-z
- `\w*\|` Match optional word characters, then match `|`
- `(?<quantity>(\d+))`
- `\|[^\W\d]*` Match optional word characters without the digits (to not overmatch the digits)
- `(?<price>(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\$))` Group price, with an optional decimal part

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IjNtM8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
%(?<name>[A-Z][a-z]*?)%<(?<product>[A-Za-z]*)>[^|]*?\|(?<quantity>\d+)\|[^\d]*(?<price>\d+(?:\.\d+)*\$)
```